# Prove the first absorption law by showing that if A and B are sets, then A ∪ (A ∩ B) = A

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My textbook is asking me to:
Prove the first absorption law by showing that if A and B are sets, then A ∪ (A ∩ B) = A.

I am a little unclear by how to prove this?

Answer (score 3):

If $x \in A \cap B\; \text{then}\; x \in A$.

Comment: Wow, simpler than I thought!

Comment: @Fogest This isn't a proof.

Comment: @crash hmmm okay. Well all I need to do is prove an existing law though right? What else would I need?

Comment: @Fogest This answer gives you a start, but you need to show mutual subset inclusion to show equality (which this answer does not show); however, the link provided by Woodface gives you a full proof of the desired equality, one that does show mutual subset inclusion.